# Adding custom methods to a Django model form produced by modelform_factory

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have this definition :

```
ProfileForm = modelform_factory(User, fields=('username'))
```

How do I add custom clean_data methods to ProfileForm ?

Comment: Remember to add the trailing comma to `('username',)` - `('username')` is not a tuple.

Comment: Thanks, I actually just did the mistake. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a model form class and pass that to [`modelform_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function). For example:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_username(self):
        """always make username lowercase"""
        return self.cleaned_data['username'].lower()

ProfileForm = modelform_factory(User, form=UserForm, fields=('username',))
```

If you need to define the form class dynamically, then you could use `type()`. [This blog post](https://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/) might help explain the idea, although it's 10 years old so the code might need to be adjusted.